# Probability-Bayes theorem

Tags: probability

The probability that bulbs are detected faulty if they are defective is 0.95 and the probability that bulbs are declared fine if in fact they are fine is 0.97. If 0.5% of the bulbs are faulty, what is the probability that a bulb that is declared faulty is fine?

Anyone can guide me for this question please?
What I did:

I intepret F:the bulbs are faulty and D: The fault is detected. And get $\Pr(F)=0.05$ and $\Pr(D|F)=0.95$ and $\Pr(D^c|F^c)=0.97$. And try to find $\Pr(D|F^c)$,which is the answer. Using Bayes theorem, however I am not sure how to find the denominator of the theorem. Can help me?
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathscr S$ be the universe of samples. We know, abstractly, that $.5\%$ of $\mathscr S$ is faulty and $99.5\%$ is fine.  We test everything.  Of the faulty $.5\%$, $95\%$ test as faulty.  Hence $.95*.5\% = .475\%$ of $\mathscr S$ is faulty and tests as faulty.  On the other hand, $.03*99.5\% = 2.985\%$ of $\mathscr S$ is fine but tests as faulty. The answer, then, is $$\frac {2.985}{2.985+.475}=\frac {2.985}{3.46} \sim .8627$$

Comment: the answer given is 0.863

Comment: @UnusualSkill   Hmmm...don't see a conceptual error in what I wrote.  Of course, there could just be a blunder.  I am good at those.  I'll check.

Comment: @UnusualSkill  I think the phrase ".05 of the bulbs" may be ambiguous.   Say we had $100$ bulbs...I am assuming that $5$ of them are faulty.  Is that how you read it?

Comment: sorry I saw wrongly, question stated 0.5%

Comment: @UnusualSkill  Good!  I will modify my solution to reflect that.

Comment: can I interpret like this: what I need to find is given that the bulb is declared faulty , what is probability that it is fine

Comment: @UnusualSkill  Absolutely.  In my approach, I simply work out what portion of the "Tested Faulty" universe is occupied by samples which are secretly fine.  Don't care about the rest of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

From the way the question is worded, it appears that you need to find $P(F^c|D)$ rather than $P(D|F^c)$, which, using Bayes' rules is
$$\begin{align}P(F^c|D)&=\frac{P(D|F^c)P(F^c)}{P(D)}\\&=\frac{P(D|F^c)P(F^c)}{P(D|F)P(F)+P(D|F^c)P(F^c)}\\&=\frac{(1-P(D^c|F^c))P(F^c)}{P(D|F)P(F)+(1-P(D^c|F^c))P(F^c)}\\&=\frac{(1-0.97)\times0.995}{(0.95\times0.005)+((1-0.97)\times0.995)}\\&\approx 0.863\end{align}$$